# MSBuild Error MSB4096 started hapening seemingly without reason

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

I have a c++ project built with QT and QT VS Tools that was working and building fine up to yesterday.
I built, pushed to git and published the latest release and now, today,
seemingly out of no reason at all my project does not compile anymore.

I started getting the following error when building:

```
Error   MSB4096 The item "GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_myqt.cpp" in item list "QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded" does not define a value for metadata "AdditionalIncludeDirectories".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded.AdditionalIncludeDirectories), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.   Kreator C:\Users\Mars\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild\qt_globals.targets    389
```

There are not git changes, and it built fine in this state yesterday.

This is the log from running MSBuild on command line:

```
D:\Source\TS2\tskreator>msbuild Kreator.sln

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
Build started 23.5.2020. 17:49:08.
Project "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Win32".
Project "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.sln" (1) is building "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (
default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "Debug\Kreator.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
Project "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj" (2) is building "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj" (2:2) on no
de 1 (Build target(s)).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "Debug\Kreator.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
PreBuildEvent:
  copy D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\*.* D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Debug\
  :VCEnd
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\msvcp100d.dll
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\msvcr100d.dll
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\QtCored4.dll
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\QtCored4.pdb
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\QtGuid4.dll
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\QtGuid4.pdb
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\QtOpenGLd4.dll
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\QtOpenGLd4.pdb
  D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\binaries\msvc\Debug\vcruntime140.dll
          9 file(s) copied.
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtUicSetModified:
Skipping target "QtUicSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtRccFilterSetModified:
Skipping target "QtRccFilterSetModified" because it has no outputs.
QtRccFilter:
Skipping target "QtRccFilter" because it has no outputs.
QtQmlSetModified:
Skipping target "QtQmlSetModified" because it has no outputs.
QtQml:
Skipping target "QtQml" because it has no outputs.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
QtMocSetModified:
Skipping target "QtMocSetModified" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
C:\Users\Mars\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild\qt_globals.targets(389,5): error MSB4096: The item "GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_myqt
.cpp" in item list "QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded" does not define a value for metadata "AdditionalIncludeDirectories".  In
 order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded.AdditionalIncludeDirectories),
 or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata. [D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Done Building Project "D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
"D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj" (Build target) (2:2) ->
(QtWork target) ->
  C:\Users\Mars\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild\qt_globals.targets(389,5): error MSB4096: The item "GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_my
qt.cpp" in item list "QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded" does not define a value for metadata "AdditionalIncludeDirectories".
In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded.AdditionalIncludeDirectories
), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata. [D:\Source\TS2\tskreator\Kreator.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.16
```

I tried cleaning and rebuilding, it did not help.

I tried restarting and updating Visual Studio to the latest version. It did not help.

I tried deleting C:\Users\Mars\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild, and it did not help.

I tried checking out previous versions, and those do not build anymore as well!
Maybe some environment problem happened?

I checked out the repo from scratch on a new folder, and the same error happens.

The node in the qt_global.target seems to have the AdditionalIncludeDirectories it is complaining about:[image]

My project is not using precompiled headers.
I tried adding logging for design time and in the %TEMP% folder the designtime log contained the error:

```
  Initializing task factory "CodeTaskFactory" from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll".
  Using "Expand" task from the task factory "Code Task Factory".
  Task "Expand"
  Done executing task "Expand".
  C:\Users\Mars\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild\qt_globals.targets(389,5): error MSB4096: The item "GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_myqt.cpp" in item list "QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded" does not define a value for metadata "AdditionalIncludeDirectories".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded.AdditionalIncludeDirectories), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.
Done building target "QtWork" in project "Kreator.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

The same error happens in both Release and Debug.
I am unable to figure out what the problem is about and googling does not return anything useful.
Do you have suggestions on what to do?

Edit:
I have found that doing exactly what the error says, and changing the qt.global.targets block that is complaining to:

[image]

Make it compile. But this is not a good solution since deleting AppData\QtMSBuild will regenerate those files and it will not compile again. Also it makes it uncompilable on a fresh checkout.

Did something change in Visual Studio and a rogue update made this requirement for prefixing the AdditionalIncludeDirectories?

Comment: Step one would be to check out a commit from yesterday (or whenever it last worked) and try building that. If that fails, then obviously it's not your code but something in your environment around it that changed.

Comment: That commit built fine yesterday but it is not building anymore. Seems like an environment problem. I tried checking out previous commits and the same error happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your project files need to be recreated, you didn't mention recreating them.

First you can make sure by looking at git/github commit history to see changes to to your project file, and then apply missing changes back manually.

Also easy way worth trying first (ex. by creating a blank new QT Project) and then in `VS Property manager -> C/C++ -> All options`: type "Force" and look what it says under "Force Include file". if there is anything copy to your original project.

How ever Qt most likely auto generates project files so you should recreate them for your sources instead probably with Qt project generator.

The `%(QtWork_ClCompile_Expanded.AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` is inserted into project file and it's not assigned a value. that's what it's causing error.

Comment: I tried reverting to previous version and previous commits. Any version I try gives the same error with any version of the vcxproj. There seems some environment problem or something akin to it...

Comment: I made it compile and I do not like how. Could you please read the ending Edit to my original post and try to understand why?

Comment: The xml block from project file is auto generated by Qt project generator, it's not part of a VS default project file. You can try to update your  `Qt VS Tools`, install new version of `Qt` and check if problem persists with new projects or just this one?

Comment: also see this link, did you remove or change C# installations? https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-614